# Rollover Image In Cell Table Overriding Previous Cell Image - Repeating Images in Table

Tags: html, css, html-table, cells, repeat

I'm trying to make rollover images with a hyperlink in each table cell, but for some reason each subsequent cell I make is overriding the cells *before* it .:. each cell becomes a repeated image. The code worked fine the first time I wrote it; this is totally out of the blue. Here are the image codes for two adjacent cells - what happens for me for some reason, the 2nd cell keeps showing up as the 1st cell image as well.

```
<table style="width: 655px; height: 630px; border: 2px dotted black;">
<tbody>
<tr align="center">    
<td style="border: 2px dotted black; width: 220px; height: 210px;"> <style type="text/css">
.rollover a {display: block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 155px;
  background-image: url( IMG1a );}
.rollover a:hover{display: block;
  width:210px;
  height: 155px;
  background-image: url( IMG1b );}
</style><div class="rollover"> <a href="link1"></a></div></td>

<td style="border: 2px dotted black; width: 220px; height: 210px;"> <style type="text/css">
.rollover a {display: block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 155px;
  background-image: url( IMG1a );}
.rollover a:hover{display: block;
  width:210px;
  height: 155px;
  background-image: url( IMG1b );}
</style><div class="rollover"> <a href="link1"></a></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you post the full relevant HTML that accompanies this?

Comment: I changed it to include the table HTML as well! Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a larger chunk of HTML I am assuming that you have this in your page verbatim. `<style>` elements are not scoped to a part of the page. So if you have these two style elements in the page, the last statement will override the first and influence both divs.

To resolve this, you have to give each `div` or `a` a specific selector, like an `id`:

```
<style type="text/css">
#first-div.rollover a {display: block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 155px;
  background-image: url( IMG1a );}
#first-div.rollover a:hover{
  background-image: url( IMG1b );}

#second-div.rollover a {display: block;
  width: 185px;
  height: 131px;
  background-image: url( IMG2a );}
#second-div.rollover a:hover{
  background-image: url( IMGb );}
</style>

<div class="rollover" id="first-div">
  <a href="link1"></a>
</div>
<div class="rollover" id="second-div">
  <a href="link2"></a>
</div>
```

And as always, include your `<style>` in your `<head>` tag, or even better in a separate file!